# Finding most frequent values in column of array in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am looking to return the most frequent occurrences in a column. I know how to do this in SQL but not SQL Alchemy. For example, I have this database with Posts. Each post has a Text Field and also a Category field. I am looking to return the top 3 categories in order, such that the following:

```
Post 1: "Text", "Food"
Post 2: "Text", "Games"
Post 2: "Text", "Games"
Post 2: "Text", "News"
Post 2: "Text", "News"
Post 2: "Text", "News"
Post 2: "Text", "Other"
Post 2: "Text", "Food"
```

would return:

```
{"News", "Games", "Food"}
```

Comment: Your output doesn't match your description. Why does `Food` appear before `Games`?

Comment: I think the question might be mis-formatted. If so, are you asking how to do a SUM AS / GROUP BY /  ORDER BY query in SA?

Comment: @Andy you are right, Food should be after.

Comment: @Dylrei pretty much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the column you're grouping on is called "category":

```
from sqlalchemy import func, desc
session.query(
    func.count(tablename.id).label('qty')
    ).group_by(tablename.category
    ).order_by(desc('qty'))
```

Comment: ...and then you'd return the top 3 by adding .limit(3)

Comment: this returns the count rather than the object itself

Answer (score 1):

@dylrei answer was just missing one bit in order to return the object and the counter

```
from sqlalchemy import func, desc
session.query(tablename.category,              <--- You need to add this
    func.count(tablename.id).label('qty')
    ).group_by(tablename.category
    ).order_by(desc('qty'))
```